# applying additional css with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap. I and created additional css file which has website specific styling inside **"app.css"** .

And created another **site.css** and written following code inside it-

```
@import url('../Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('../Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css');
@import url('../Content/bootstrap/css/app.css');
```

And I used site.css in my layout file.

And inside app.css written following styling-

```
.margin0 {
margin:0;
}

.text-span{
    width: 100%;
  }

.text-center {
text-align:center;
}
```

like that.

And then i'm applying above classes with bootstrap styling as-

```
<div class="span4">
   <span class="text-span hideOverflow">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "JumpLinks", @style = "font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;" })</span>
   <span style="color: #ADADAD; font-size: 11px;" class="text-span margin0">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)</span>
</div>
```

Now problem is that my **margin0** is not applying as I want. **The bootstrap style effect overriding my css effect**. And I don't want let it happen. How to resolve this problem ?

I inspected the element then my class is overridden by bootstraps below class-

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
min-height: 30px;
margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ePQ9L/

Comment: @ArunPJohny : I checked link provided by you. But I'm also not getting that why it's not working in my web page.

Comment: Use Firebug to examine the css and see what rule is overriding your style. I'd recommend not using @import as it's generally thought to have a slight performance deficit compared to a regular link for your stylesheets. Also Bootstrap now has built-in text alignment classes making yours redundant: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="span4">
<span class="text-span hideOverflow">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", 
 new { id =  item.Id }, new { @class = "JumpLinks", @style = "font-size:13px;
  font-  weight:bold;" })</span>
    <span style="color: #ADADAD; font-size: 11px;margin:0px !important; " class="
     text-span">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer updated, I just added `css` you used in class as style over span and marked it as important..this will work now and override all other styles etc...'

Comment: I don't want to set margin as its inline property. Then how to do this ?

Comment: Hi, well without seeing what is overriding your `margin0` class i won't be able to say anything...that's why i suggested inline..